# how to select data that contains multiple row from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pandas-groupby

I wrote the command bellow :

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['CHAUFFEUR','comportement de conduit'])['comportement de conduit'].count())
```

I get the dataframe bellow :

| CHAUFFEUR | comportement de conduit | comportement de conduit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABBAD DJELLOUL | bad driving behaviour(reduce your acceleration) | 1 |
| ABBOU ABD EL KADER | bad driving behaviour | 5 |
|  | bad driving behaviour(reduce your acceleration,increase your speed) | 14 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ZIANE ABDELKADER | good driving behaviour(try to reduce acceleration) | 18 |
|  | normal driving behaviour | 24 |
|  | very good driving behaviour | 4 |

Now I need to select for each **CHAUFFEUR** all numbers of his **comportement de conduit**
for example for the second **CHAUUFEUR** named **ABBOU ABD EL KADER** i need to select only :

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| bad driving behaviour | 5 |
| bad driving behaviour(reduce your acceleration) | 41 |

So how can I do it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use str.contains can find the answer

```
df = df[df['comportement de conduit'].str.contains('bad driving behaviour')]
```

This will show you a row for the included string.

I hope you solve it well.

Answer (score 0):

fill the null values with forward fill to fill in the blank values.

make the empty cell as np.nan

```
df['CHAUFFEUR'] = df['CHAUFFEUR'].str.strip().replace("", np.nan)
```

```
df['CHAUFFEUR'] = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

OR

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.strip().replace("", np.nan).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: @miss-chl,  is that what you were looking for? did it addressed the question?

Comment: not really what i need exactly is to count for every driver (**CHAUFFEUR**) the number of different classe béhavior